# ST_Overlaps and related

Tags: postgis, st-intersects

I have a table with ~15K records consisting in points with a 200m buffer and I need to investigate how many of them are in proximity of polygons contained in another table (~20K).

I wrote a function (really simple one) which uses a record variable (rowgeo) and then uses ST_Overlaps like this:

```
SELECT gid 
FROM pi a
WHERE ST_Overlaps(a.geom, rowgeo.buffer) INTO var
```

well, the function is dramatically slow... it's running since yesterday morning. Both tables have a gist index on geometry column.

Any hints?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to buffer points before comparing.
Use [`ST_Dwithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) and a [`JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html):

```
SELECT table1.gid
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON ST_DWithin(table1.geom,table2.geom,200);
```

Make sure, that both `geom` fields are in same SRID.
The distance value must be in the unit of the SRID.